# Calculate the Months between two months

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my project, i am saving all the dates in the form of string like say "07/26/2013" in the database.But now, there came a situation where i need to retrieve two dates and then check the months between those two start and end month.

Eg: If the start date is 01/01/2013 and the end month is 05/01/2013, i should get the answer like {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"} or {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05"}. I have tried collections but receive an error index out of range. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!
Sara.

Comment: can you share your code snippeT?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there is a simpler way to do this with Linq, but a simple loop would do the job:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(startString);
DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(endString);
List<string> months = new List<string>();
while (start.Month <= end.Month)
{
    months.Add(start.ToString("MMM"));
    start = start.AddMonths(1);
}
string output = string.Join(",", months.ToArray());
```

See this MSDN page for info on formatting the month output via ToString(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Comment: Thank you sooo muchh!! You are awesome!! That totally worked for me :)

Comment: What if start and end are in the same month ?

Comment: You can check `while(start.Month <= end.Month)` instead. In fact, I'll change my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Just for fun, here's the linq answer: `var months = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(end - start).TotalDays + 1).Select(a => start.AddDays(a).ToString("MMM")).Distinct();`

Answer (score 0):

This takes one of your dates and converts it to the proper string. Getting month of it is not a problem, and I guess you are mistaking because of conflict in which dates are converted to and from string on your computer.

```
        string date1 = "05/01/2013";
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(date1, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you but the code snippet in the prev answer helped me! Once again, thank you so much for reply me :)